# What is the equivalent of the type Image in C# asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am working on a Web API using asp.NET Core that requires an image parameter in a class. The type "Image" does not exist in asp.net core nor does the "System.Drawings.Image". What can i use instead?

Comment: There is nothing built in. These classes rely heavily on GDI/GDI+ which is Windows specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have read, there is currently no support for the `System.Drawing` namespace. [Here is a link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/) to a blog post by Jeffrey Fritz about ASP.NET Core. If you search the page for `System.Drawing`, you'll see a comment about the lack of support.

I haven't seen anything recent that suggests that it will be available due to its cross-platform nature and the fact that imaging requires interaction with native libraries.

Edit: It looks like there are some basic `System.Drawing` primitives available in the [src folder on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Drawing.Primitives/src/System/Drawing). However, I do not see anything for the `Image` or `Bitmap` class.

Update: there is a [System.Drawing](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3634) implementation in Mono. See the comment from Miguel.

Comment: There are tons of threads on GitHub CoreFX repo, so that's more direct than any other blog posts. Of course, blog posts help summerize the key points sometimes, but they can easily go out of date as the repo moves forward so fast.

Answer (score 1):

You may store your images in the wwwroot folder from which you can serve them
with no authorization checks.
If authorization checks is required, store them outside of the wwwroot folder  and serve them through a controller action, returning a FileResult objet

If you need processing of images, ImageProcessor Core may help you:
https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/tree/Core/